# Why is $\frac{\sin (-x)}{\cos (-x)}$ not equal to $\frac{-\sin (x)}{-\cos (x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is the first scenario I have seen of math semi-contradicting its rules. By the negative trig identity definition, shouldn't $-\sin(x) = \sin(-x)$? Therefore, why is the title statement wrong?

Comment: because $\cos(-x)=\cos(x),$ not $-\cos(x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core reason is tied to the notion of an even/odd function.

An even function $f$ satisfies the condition $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

An odd function $f$ satisfies the condition $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$.

Sine is an odd function and cosine is even. Therefore:

$$\frac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)} = \frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

Notice this differs by a factor of $(-1)$ from your proposed solution.

Comment: I read my textbook incorrectly I understand now. Thank you for the prompt reply

Comment: If the answer satisfied your needs, don't forget to click the green check mark to accept it so that others who ask the same question will know it was right!

Answer (score 1):

The function $ f(x) = \sin(x) $ is an **odd** function because $f$'s graph is symmetric with respect to the origin $(0,0)$. $f$ is odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

In the graph below, the blue curve depicts $f(x) = \sin(x)$, which clearly is symmetric with respect to the origin. Thus, $f(-x) = \sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$.

[image]

On the other hand, the function $ g(x) = \cos(x) $ is an **even** function because $g$'s graph is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. $g$ is even if $g(-x) = g(x)$.

In the graph below, the red curve depicts $g(x) = \cos(x)$, which clearly is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. Thus, $g(-x) = \cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

[image]

Hence $$\frac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)} \neq \frac{-\sin(x)}{-\cos(x)}$$